# Wireless AP band detection

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

Can 2.4 GHz wireless client see/find 5 GHz SSID networks in the range?
Can 5 GHz wireless client see/find 2.4 GHz SSID networks in the range?

Is there any criteria of wireless networks found by wireless client in the range? Is there any possibility that SSID is filtered out?

How can I determine band (2.4 and 5 GHz) information of wireless networks in my range?

Answer (score 1):

> Can 2.4 GHz wireless client see/find 5 GHz SSID networks in the range?

No, unless its a dual band adaptor

> Can 5 GHz wireless client see/find 2.4 GHz SSID networks in the range?

Since most devices that do 5ghz are dualband, inadvertantly.

> Is there any criteria of wireless networks found by wireless client in the range? Is there any possibility that SSID is filtered out?

Well, in theory, there's a few bands not everywhere uses that may not turn up

> How can I determine band (2.4 and 5 GHz) information of wireless networks in my range?

You do a access point survey. You can throw something suitable on a mobile phone (for walking around)

My desktop's got [acrylic wi-fi home installed for testing](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/), so it'll have to do. There's dozens of options here so there might be some other options. They all have more or less the same features.

[image: ![enter image description here]

So, It shows you what APs there, are, what channels they use and so on. My 5ghz tabs are blank since this is a single band client. The nice thing is many of these *also* show where they overlap and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Whether two different networks can see each other would depend on devices, but information about frequency is given by Channel. For example, Channel 10 means 2457 MHz, Channel 5 means 2432 MHz and so on…

Comment: What is that depends on device? What the channel info of 5 GHz SSID networks?